# 2 sets of Custom Membership in ASP .Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I can setup custom membership easily enough, but what if I need two sets i.e. admin for control panel and registered for logged on customers.  This would mean two seperate tables to get users from.  My question is how can I integrate the two to control through 1 custom membership and how can I authenticate on the controller for the 2?

Comment: This seems to me like two different roles more than two different memberships. Can't you simply use admin and customer roles to differenciate your users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't separate users this way, you'd implement a [custom role provider](http://kitsula.com/Article/Custom-Role-Provider-for-MVC) and allocate these roles to the user.  So say you have created two roles **admin** and **user** you'd set an attribute to your controller like so:

**Admin page controller**

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult AdminAction() { }
```

**User page controller**

```
[Authorize(Roles = "User")]
public ActionResult UserAction() { }
```

If you wanted your administrators to view all logged in user pages, you'd simply just assign the **user** role to your administrators.

Comment: Thats great and what I envisaged but my mind is blank on how to define the roles, I don't want to create a roles table, if possible would like to change the ValidateUser() of custom membership to check which table to use for admin/user and set the role manually here, possible?

Comment: @user1166905 you could create a custom `MembershipUser` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912121/implementing-custom-membershipuser) with a `Roles` attribute (maybe a comma delimited string) that is set in your `ValidateUser()` method based on where they came from. Then you could create a custom attribute (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2933/Attributes-in-C) where this attribute would take the role name as a string and then query your custom user class for the respective role.